Why Audio is downloading, but it's not playing?
Why it's returning null audio clip and it's not playing, but when I select the clip, and start playing It, it's playing. Why this happening?
Clip settings and preview - Audio is playing when I press play button in audio (clip) preview
Audio source clip field returning this
Script:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using SFB;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

namespace SlimeEngine.LevelEditor
{
    public class MusicSelector : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public AudioSource audioSource;

        public void OpenSongSelector()
        {
            string[] paths = StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel("Open File", "", "wav", false);
            if (paths.Length > 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(LoadAudio(paths[0]));
            }
        }

        IEnumerator LoadAudio(string path)
        {
            using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip("file://" + path, AudioType.WAV))
            {
                yield return www.SendWebRequest();

                if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
                {
                    AudioClip audioClip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
                    audioSource.clip = audioClip;
                    audioSource.Play();
                    Debug.Log(path);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Error loading audio: " + www.error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Tried using UnityWebRequest instend of WWW, but it's not working and giving same result. After reading the forums, I realized that the issue may be in the Load Type, which by default is set to Decompression On Load.

Move the return statement after the If/else.  You are returning instead of playing.
